# create partition error manjaro installer

Tags: partition, manjaro, bios, mbr

I am installing Manjaro with dual boot Windows 10. I created a '/' partition and a swap partition from a 200 GB unallocated space. When I hit install, it shows an error and fails to create partitions. My system uses BIOS and I use Rufus to load the ISO file on my USB. It automatically changed the partition type to MBR and BIOS. Also, the fast boot is disabled on Windows. I'm really confused. I'm new to Manjaro.

Hope I gave you enough info. Simply Windows has 3 primary partition that is extremely odd. And I need more primary partition. I don't remember that my previous Windows installations were using 3 primary partitions.

Comment: You may want to edit the question and share the error message when the installer fails to create the partitions. As far as I know, Windows 10 uses GPT, so that I am surprised to read that "it" (what is "it"?) changes the partition type to MBR. Perhaps adding a little clarity here would help understanding what is going on.

Comment: I changed my windows to 8 and it doesn't have any system reserved partition. So I successfully installed manjaro. Thanks